# Declaring Unknown Type Variable in Python?

Tags: python, types

I have a situation in Python(cough, homework) where I need to multiply EACH ELEMENT in a given list of objects a specified number of times and return the output of the elements.  The problem is that the sample inputs given are of different types.  For example, one case may input a list of strings whose elements I need to multiply while the others may be ints.  So my return type needs to vary.  I would like to do this without having to test what every type of object is.  Is there a way to do this?  I know in C# i could just use "var" but I don't know if such a thing exists in Python?

I realize that variables don't have to be declared, but in this case I can't see any way around it.  Here's the function I made:

```
def multiplyItemsByFour(argsList):

output = ????

for arg in argsList:
        output += arg * 4

return output
```

See how I need to add to the output variable.  If I just try to take away the output assignment on the first line, I get an error that the variable was not defined.  But if I assign it a 0 or a "" for an empty string, an exception could be thrown since you can't add 3 to a string or "a" to an integer, etc...

Here are some sample inputs and outputs:

```
Input:  ('a','b')  Output:  'aaaabbbb'
Input:  (2,3,4)    Output:  36
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you readup on Python before your exam. Most dynamic languages like Python do not need type declaration

Comment: To the downvoter, I realize this is homework but the question has nothing to do with the actual homework assignment.  This problem could just as well be applied to anything.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "multiply a list". From comments to one of the answers, it's clear that you do not mean the usual semantics of operator `*` in Python (which is to replicate the list).

Comment: Can you give several examples of inputs and their corresponding outputs?  It's rather unclear from the question.

Comment: For the record, in C# you can't use `var` to get varying return types. `var` means variable, but it is still statically typed, and cannot be changed. Using `var` just shifts the responsibility of working out what type the variable is from you to the compiler.

Comment: @Adam  Sorry.  I added some sample inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy in Python. You need to get the type of the data in your list - use the type() function on the first item - type(argsList[0]).  Then to initialize output (where you now have ????) you need the 'zero' or nul value for that type.  So just as int() or float() or str() returns the zero or nul for their type so to will type(argsList[0])() return the zero or nul value for whatever type you have in your list.

So, here is your function with one minor modification:

```
def multiplyItemsByFour(argsList):
    output = type(argsList[0])()
    for arg in argsList:
        output += arg * 4
    return output
```

Works with::
argsList = `[1, 2, 3, 4]`  or  `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]`  or  `"abcdef"` ... etc,

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I was really curious as to how this could be done, not simply for others to solve my homework.  You did both :) This could come in handy for the future!  Some of these other solutions will work, but this is the simplest and most clear.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your studies and thanks for the check.

Answer (score 7):

```
def fivetimes(anylist):
  return anylist * 5
```

As you see, if you're given a list argument, there's no need for any assignment whatsoever in order to "multiply it a given number of times and return the output".  You talk about a *given* list; how is it *given* to you, if not (the most natural way) as an argument to your function?  Not that it matters much -- if it's a global variable, a property of the object that's your argument, and so forth, this still doesn't necessitate any assignment.

If you were "homeworkically" forbidden from using the `*` operator of lists, and just required to implement it yourself, this would require assignment, but no declaration:

```
def multiply_the_hard_way(inputlist, multiplier):
    outputlist = []
    for i in range(multiplier):
        outputlist.extend(inputlist)
    return outputlist
```

You can simply make the empty list "magicaly appear": there's no need to "declare" it as being anything whatsoever, it's an empty list and the Python compiler knows it as well as you or any reader of your code does.  Binding it to the name `outputlist` doesn't require you to perform any special ritual either, just the binding (aka assignment) itself: names don't have types, only *objects* have types... that's Python!-)

**Edit**: OP now says output must not be a list, but rather int, float, or maybe string, and he is given no indication of what.  I've asked for clarification -- multiplying a list ALWAYS returns a list, so clearly he must mean something different from what he originally said, that he had to multiply a list.  Meanwhile, here's another attempt at mind-reading. Perhaps he must return a list where EACH ITEM of the input list is multiplied by the same factor (whether that item is an int, float, string, list, ...).  Well then:

```
define multiply_each_item(somelist, multiplier):
  return [item * multiplier for item in somelist]
```

Look ma, no hands^H^H^H^H^H assignment.  (This is known as a "list comprehension", btw).

Or maybe (unlikely, but my mind-reading hat may be suffering interference from my tinfoil hat, will need to go to the mad hatter's shop to have them tuned) he needs to (say) multiply each list item *as if* they were the same type as the first item, but return them as their original type, so that for example

```
>>> mystic(['zap', 1, 23, 'goo'], 2)
['zapzap', 11, 2323, 'googoo']
>>> mystic([23, '12', 15, 2.5], 2)
[46, '24', 30, 4.0]
```

Even this highly-mystical spec COULD be accomodated...:

```
>>> def mystic(alist, mul):
...   multyp = type(alist[0])
...   return [type(x)(mul*multyp(x)) for x in alist]
...
```

...though I very much doubt it's the spec actually encoded in the mysterious runes of that homework assignment. Just about ANY precise spec can be either implemented or proven to be likely impossible as stated (by requiring you to solve the Halting Problem or demanding that P==NP, say;-).  That may take some work ("prove the 4-color theorem", for example;-)... but still less than it takes to magically divine what the actual spec IS, from a collection of mutually contradictory observations, no examples, etc.  Though in our daily work as software developer (ah for the good old times when all we had to face was homework!-) we DO meet a lot of such cases of course (and have to solve them to earn our daily bread;-).

*EditEdit*: finally seeing a precise spec I point out I already implemented that one, anyway, here it goes again:

```
def multiplyItemsByFour(argsList):
  return [item * 4 for item in argsList]
```

*EditEditEdit*: finally/finally seeing a MORE precise spec, with (luxury!-) *examples*:

```
Input: ('a','b') Output: 'aaaabbbb' Input: (2,3,4) Output: 36
```

So then what's wanted it the *summation* (and you can't use `sum` as it wouldn't work on strings) of the items in the input list, each multiplied by four.  My preferred solution:

```
def theFinalAndTrulyRealProblemAsPosed(argsList):
  items = iter(argsList)
  output = next(items, []) * 4
  for item in items:
    output += item * 4
  return output
```

If you're forbidden from using some of these constructs, such as built-ins `items` and `iter`, there are many other possibilities (slightly inferior ones) such as:

```
def theFinalAndTrulyRealProblemAsPosed(argsList):
  if not argsList: return None
  output = argsList[0] * 4
  for item in argsList[1:]:
    output += item * 4
  return output
```

For an empty `argsList`, the first version returns `[]`, the second one returns `None` -- not sure what you're supposed to do in that corner case anyway.

Comment: Thanks; that makes sense.  The output isn't a list, however.  The output will either be a string, int, floating point, etc. I don't know what the output type will be.  And I can't just say output *= x because it's expecting output to already be defined.  I can't define it, however, because to define it I must say output = "" or output = 0, etc.  So I may have to manually test the types in the list then assign the output variable to that type.

Comment: @Austin, the exact, precise specifications of what you're trying to do, to this point, appear maddeningly vague and shifty -- originally you say you need to multiply a list of objects, now that the result must not be a list, etc; please edit your question to clarify, you can't expect mindreading -- surely your homework's specs ARE written down SOMEwhere, right?!  Meanwhile I'll edit my answer to muse about other ways one might possibly read your maddeningly vague words.

Comment: @Austin, tx for clarifying, my solution for that variant of the spec was already in my answer but I added it again at the very end just to make it easy for you to find -- hope it helps!

Comment: @Alex, I appreciate it.  Sorry for the vagueness.  I should have read over it some more before I posted.

Comment: @Austin NP, I was quite verbose in my answer. So does the last tidbit of my answer, the list comprehension, solve your problem? If your homework conditions forbid that you could start `output = []` and then in the loop do `output.append(item * 4)` -- I showed that doesn't require any type or declaration either in another part of my answer. Anyway, I do hope this helped.

Comment: @Austin, and YET ANOTHER attempt added at the end of the answer now that I've finally seen example inputs and outputs from you (requiring a summation that was not previously in the specs;-). Hope THIS one's acceptable...?

Comment: @Alex, That partially works.  I am not getting the correct outputs, however.  For example, if I input (2,3), I get 14 as an output instead of 20.

Comment: @Austin, I get 20 with both versions, the good one and the not-so-good one, in the current version -- there was transiently a version of the not-so-good one that omitted an obviously needed `* 4` and would have given the erroneous result you mention, but surely that would have been obvious from the minimal code inspection required before running it, so I'm perplexed.

Comment: ...But please don't use camelCased function names :)

Comment: @Triptych lol.  I agree.  Unfortunately that is what my professor prefers.  I know, it's crazy to not capitalize the first letter of a sentence, so why do a function?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the purpose of your homework is to expose you to "duck typing".  The basic idea is that you don't worry about the types too much, you just worry about whether the *behaviors* work correctly.  A classic example:

```
def add_two(a, b):
    return a + b

print add_two(1, 2)  # prints 3

print add_two("foo", "bar")  # prints "foobar"

print add_two([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5])  # prints [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Notice that when you `def` a function in Python, you don't declare a return type anywhere.  It is perfectly okay for the same function to return different types based on its arguments.  It's considered a virtue, even; consider that in Python we only need one definition of `add_two()` and we can add integers, add floats, concatenate strings, and join lists with it.  Statically typed languages would require multiple implementations, unless they had an escape such as `variant`, but Python is dynamically typed.  (Python is strongly typed, but dynamically typed.  Some will tell you Python is weakly typed, but it isn't.  In a weakly typed language such as JavaScript, the expression `1 + "1"` will give you a result of 2; in Python this expression just raises a `TypeError` exception.)

It is considered very poor style to try to test the arguments to figure out their types, and then do things based on the types.  If you need to make your code robust, you can always use a `try` block:

```
def safe_add_two(a, b):
    try:
        return a + b
    except TypeError:
        return None
```

See also the Wikipedia page on [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: Thanks!  I understand exactly what you mean.  I didn't know there was a word for that.  I was under the impression that dynamic types in Python meant I could simply define the variable and assign it a type later, but it looks like there is a catch.  I'll try the try block and see how it goes.

Comment: The dynamic types in Python have two major pieces: (0) variables are not declared; what you do is "bind" a name to an object; (1) types are checked at runtime, so you don't need to declare things.  If you execute the code `a = 1` what actually happens is that the name "a" is now bound (in some scope, possibly global, possibly local) to an object of type integer, with a value of 1.  It is perfectly legal to hen say `a = "foo"` and rebind the name "a" to a string object with value "foo".  Then, because types are not checked until they have to be, duck-typing functions are possible.

Comment: The try block is just an example of how to write a try block; you almost certainly don't need one for your homework.  In Python, it is usually the best practice to simply let exceptions happen.  `add_two()` is almost certainly preferable to `safe_add_two()` in the general case.  If the caller needs to bullet-proof things, the caller should wrap the call in a try block.  If you pass bad args to `add_two()`, the backtrace from the exception will point straight at the line of code that caused the bug; `safe_add_two()` masks the actual bug.

Comment: For a good intro to the idea of names, please see: http://rg03.wordpress.com/2007/04/21/semantics-of-python-variable-names-from-a-c-perspective/

Comment: See also this discussion of whether Python is strongly typed.  http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=7590

Comment: Now that you posted examples, I understand what is going on.  Please see my other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is for Python beginners?  To me, the cleanest way to do this is with reduce() and lambda, both of which are not typical beginner tools, and sometimes discouraged even for experienced Python programmers:

```
def multiplyItemsByFour(argsList):
    if not argsList:
        return None
    newItems = [item * 4 for item in argsList]
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, newItems)
```

Like Alex Martelli, I've thrown in a quick test for an empty list at the beginning which returns None.  Note that if you are using Python 3, you must import functools to use reduce().

Essentially, the reduce(lambda...) solution is very similar to the other suggestions to set up an accumulator using the first input item, and then processing the rest of the input items; but is simply more concise.

Comment: You can also `import operator` and then use `operator.add` instead of the lambda you wrote to sum two numbers.  I've seen that as the canonical way to reduce a list with duck typing.  To my surprise the `sum()` added to Python 2.3 doesn't work that way.

Comment: @steveha:  Interesting.  The docs make a point to note that operator.add is for numbers while operator.concat is for sequences (including strings).  But indeed, add works like the '+' operator (while concat really does only concatenate).  Still, for such a short example, I like to avoid imports, especially since it doesn't otherwise require imports (unless using Python 3, as mentioned).

Comment: @steveha: I agree with you that sum() should just be repeated application of the '+' operator, especially given the actual behavior of operator.add.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare variable types in python; a variable has the type of whatever's assigned to it.

EDIT:

To solve the re-stated problem, try this:

```
def multiplyItemsByFour(argsList):

output = argsList.pop(0) * 4

for arg in argsList:
        output += arg * 4

return output
```

(This is probably not the most pythonic way of doing this, but it should at least start off your output variable as the right type, assuming the whole list is of the same type)

Comment: Yes, but the variable has to have an assignment.  If I need to add to or multiply the variable and it is not defined, I will get a "local variable 'output' referenced before assignment."

Comment: What would you expect from xyz*6 if xyz has not previously appeared in the program?  You can always wrap stuff in try:, except NameError:

Comment: Yea that's a good idea. It just seems like I should be able to do this without having to try/catch.  I should be able to say something like output = nothing and have the type defined later.

Comment: You can say a=0, then say a =[1,2,3] later.

Answer (score 1):

Python is dynamically typed, you don't need to declare the type of a variable, because a variable doesn't have a type, only values do. (Any variable can store any value, a value never changes its type during its lifetime.)

```
def do_something(x):
    return x * 5
```

This will work for any `x` you pass to it, the actual result depending on what type the value in `x` has. If `x` contains a number it will just do regular multiplication, if it contains a string the string will be repeated five times in a row, for lists and such it will repeat the list five times, and so on. For custom types (classes) it depends on whether the class has an operation defined for the multiplication operator.

Comment: What if x needs to be added to, however?  I can't simply say x *= 3 because it's expecting x to already be defined.  And I can't define it if I don't know what type to initially assign it.  I couldn't say x = 0 then operate on it later because it may be a string I'm dealing with.

Comment: You don't assign it a type.  A variable doesn't have a type, its value does. Any variable can hold any generic object.

Comment: Yes, you can say `x *= 3`. Yes, `x` is already defined - it's right there in the function argument list, and that's its definition. No, you don't need a type to declare variables in Python.

Comment: @Pavel, Sorry, I see what you mean.  But what if x wasn't an argument from the outside?  What if x was local to the function?

Answer (score 1):

You gave these sample inputs and outputs:

Input: ('a','b') Output: 'aaaabbbb' Input: (2,3,4) Output: 36

I don't want to write the solution to your homework for you, but I do want to steer you in the correct direction.  But I'm still not sure I understand what your problem is, because the problem as I understand it seems a bit difficult for an intro to Python class.

The most straightforward way to solve this requires that the arguments be passed in a list.  Then, you can look at the first item in the list, and work from that.  Here is a function that requires the caller to pass in a list of two items:

```
def handle_list_of_len_2(lst):
   return lst[0] * 4 + lst[1] * 4
```

Now, how can we make this extend past two items?  Well, in your sample code you weren't sure what to assign to your variable output.  How about assigning lst[0]?  Then it always has the correct type.  Then you could loop over all the other elements in lst and accumulate to your output variable using += as you wrote.  If you don't know how to loop over a list of items but skip the first thing in the list, Google search for "python list slice".

Now, how can we make this not require the user to pack up everything into a list, but just call the function?  What we really want is some way to accept whatever arguments the user wants to pass to the function, and make a list out of them.  Perhaps there is special syntax for declaring a function where you tell Python you just want the arguments bundled up into a list.  You might check a [good tutorial](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/python_101/python_101.html) and see what it says about how to define a function.

Now that we have covered (very generally) how to accumulate an answer using +=, let's consider other ways to accumulate an answer.  If you know how to use a list comprehension, you could use one of those to return a new list based on the argument list, with the multiply performed on each argument; you could then somehow reduce the list down to a single item and return it.  Python 2.3 and newer have a built-in function called `sum()` and you might want to read up on that.  [EDIT: Oh drat, `sum()` only works on numbers.  See note added at end.]

I hope this helps.  If you are still very confused, I suggest you contact your teacher and ask for clarification.  Good luck.

P.S. Python 2.x have a built-in function called `reduce()` and it is possible to implement `sum()` using `reduce()`.  However, the creator of Python thinks it is better to just use `sum()` and in fact he removed `reduce()` from Python 3.0 (well, he moved it into a module called `functools`).

P.P.S. If you get the list comprehension working, here's one more thing to think about.  If you use a list comprehension and then pass the result to `sum()`, you build a list to be used once and then discarded.  Wouldn't it be neat if we could get the result, but instead of building the whole list and then discarding it we could just have the `sum()` function consume the list items as fast as they are generated?  You might want to read this: [[Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

EDIT: Oh drat, I assumed that Python's `sum()` builtin would use duck typing.  Actually it is documented to work on numbers, only.  I'm disappointed!  I'll have to search and see if there were any discussions about that, and see why they did it the way they did; they probably had good reasons.  Meanwhile, you might as well use your += solution.  Sorry about that.

EDIT: Okay, reading through other answers, I now notice two ways suggested for peeling off the first element in the list.

For simplicity, because you seem like a Python beginner, I suggested simply using `output = lst[0]` and then using list slicing to skip past the first item in the list.  However, Wooble in his answer suggested using `output = lst.pop(0)` which is a very clean solution: it gets the zeroth thing on the list, and then you can just loop over the list and you automatically skip the zeroth thing.  However, this "mutates" the list!  It's better if a function like this does not have "side effects" such as modifying the list passed to it.  (Unless the list is a special list made just for that function call, such as a `*args` list.)  Another way would be to use the "list slice" trick to make a copy of the list that has the first item removed.  Alex Martelli provided an example of how to make an "iterator" using a Python feature called `iter()`, and then using iterator to get the "next" thing.  Since the iterator hasn't been used yet, the next thing is the zeroth thing in the list.  That's not really a beginner solution but it is the most elegant way to do this in Python; you could pass a really huge list to the function, and Alex Martelli's solution will neither mutate the list nor waste memory by making a copy of the list.

Comment: +1 for trying to explain concepts, especially given the 'beginner' and 'homework' tags.

Answer (score 0):

No need to test the objects, just multiply away!

```
'this is a string' * 6
14 * 6
[1,2,3] * 6
```

all just work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def timesfourlist(list):
 nextstep = map(times_four, list)
 sum(nextstep)
```

map performs the function passed in on each element of the list(returning a new list) and then sum does the += on the list.

Comment: The input can contain strings, and sum() doesn't accept strings.

Comment: Well doesn't that beat all but the idea is the same as long as you specify the computation without specifying a default.  In the example replacing sum with reduce(+,nextstep) ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fill in the blank in your code, you could try setting `object=arglist[0].__class__()` to give it the zero equivalent value of that class.

```
>>> def multiplyItemsByFour(argsList):
    output = argsList[0].__class__()
    for arg in argsList:
            output += arg * 4
    return output

>>> multiplyItemsByFour('ab')
'aaaabbbb'
>>> multiplyItemsByFour((2,3,4))
36
>>> multiplyItemsByFour((2.0,3.3))
21.199999999999999
```

This will crash if the list is empty, but you can check for that case at the beginning of the function and return whatever you feel appropriate.

Comment: It is better and simpler to just say `output = argsList[0]` and then modify the for loop to not add the zeroth item in the list.  Otherwise you are asking for trouble... for example, it would be legal to make a class K that is exactly like `int` except its default value is 1 instead of 0.  Please see my long answer for more thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex Martelli, you have the best possible solution:

```
def theFinalAndTrulyRealProblemAsPosed(argsList):
    items = iter(argsList)
    output = next(items, []) * 4
    for item in items:
        output += item * 4
    return output
```

This is beautiful and elegant.  First we create an iterator with `iter()`, then we use `next()` to get the first object in the list.  Then we accumulate as we iterate through the rest of the list, and we are done.  We never need to know the type of the objects in argsList, and indeed they can be of different types as long as all the types can have operator `+` applied with them.  This is duck typing.

For a moment there last night I was confused and thought that you wanted a function that, instead of taking an explicit list, just took one or more arguments.

```
def four_x_args(*args):
    return theFinalAndTrulyRealProblemAsPosed(args)
```

The `*args` argument to the function tells Python to gather up all arguments to this function and make a tuple out of them; then the tuple is bound to the name `args`.  You can easily make a list out of it, and then you could use the `.pop(0)` method to get the first item from the list.  This costs the memory and time to build the list, which is why the `iter()` solution is so elegant.

```
def four_x_args(*args):
    argsList = list(args)  # convert from tuple to list
    output = argsList.pop(0) * 4
    for arg in argsList:
        output += arg * 4
    return output
```

This is just Wooble's solution, rewritten to use *args.

Examples of calling it:

```
print four_x_args(1)  # prints 4
print four_x_args(1, 2)  # prints 12
print four_x_args('a')  # prints 'aaaa'
print four_x_args('ab', 'c') # prints 'ababababcccc'
```

Finally, I'm going to be malicious and complain about the solution you accepted.  That solution depends on the object's base class having a sensible null or zero, but not all classes have this.  `int()` returns `0`, and `str()` returns `''` (null string), so they work.  But how about this:

```
class NaturalNumber(int):
    """
    Exactly like an int, but only values >= 1 are possible.
    """
    def __new__(cls, initial_value=1):        
        try:
            n = int(initial_value)
            if n < 1:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError, "NaturalNumber() initial value must be an int() >= 1"
        return super(NaturalNumber, cls).__new__ (cls, n)


argList = [NaturalNumber(n) for n in xrange(1, 4)]

print theFinalAndTrulyRealProblemAsPosed(argList)  # prints correct answer: 24

print NaturalNumber()  # prints 1
print type(argList[0])()  # prints 1, same as previous line

print multiplyItemsByFour(argList)  # prints 25!
```

Good luck in your studies, and I hope you enjoy Python as much as I do.

Comment: @steveha, thanks for your response as well as everyone else's.  I especially appreicate yours and Alex's very thorough responses.  I realize there were a lot of better solutions than the one I chose, but I wanted to choose the solution that was as simple and clear as possible.